# Pandas - Create dynamic column(s) from a single column's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have JSON data which I am planning after converting it to desired dataframe, will concat with another dataframe.

Participant

---

```
**row 1** [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'founder'}, {'type': 'owner'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Lichun Du'}}]

**row 2** [{'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Erik Mølgaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Dorte Bøcker Linde'}}]

**row 3** [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Kristian Løth Hougaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'WORLD JET HOLDING ApS'}}]
```

However, I want it like this where dynamically the column will be generated and "N" of Participant#N Role or Participant#N Name should be the maximum number of participant present in the rows of the dataframe overall  :

[image: Desired Dataframe]

So far I have tried:
**Try 01:**

```
participants = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(x)) for x in responses['participants']])
print(participants.transpose())
```

I could not find any relevant post to move forward to the desired dataframe.

**Try 02:**

```
responses['Role of Participants'] = [x[0]['roles'] for x in participants['roles']]
responses['Participant Name'] = [x[0]['life'] for x in participants['participants']]
```

But it just returned only the first type object in role and first name object of life for each data where there can be multiple.

Comment: please provide what you tried and make an effort on the formatting

Comment: @furas, in the get_column function, how I can exclude name and roles of participants after 10th participants? I want to show upto 10th participant for each row of company data or less if it have less than 10? Please give me some suggestions atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run one `apply()` which will use `for`-loop to convert list to  `Series` with headers - it can use `enumerate` to put correct number in headers.

Because some rows have less participants so it puts `NaN` which you can later fill with empty strings.

And next you can use `join()` to add all as new columns. Because headers are create in `apply()` so you don't have to create them in `join()`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'participants': 
[
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'founder'}, {'type': 'owner'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Lichun Du'}}],
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Erik Mølgaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Dorte Bøcker Linde'}}],
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Kristian Løth Hougaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'WORLD JET HOLDING ApS'}}],
]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_names(cell):
    
    all_names = pd.Series(dtype=object)
    
    for number, item in enumerate(cell, 1):
        name = item['life']['name']
        all_names[f'Participant #{number} Name'] = name

    return all_names

def get_roles(cell):
    
    all_roles = pd.Series(dtype=object)
    
    for number, item in enumerate(cell, 1):
        roles = [role['type'] for role in item['roles']]
        all_roles[f'Participant #{number} Role'] = ",".join(roles)

    return all_roles

roles = df['participants'].apply(get_roles)
roles = roles.fillna('')  # put empty string in place of NaN

names = df['participants'].apply(get_names)
names = names.fillna('')  # put empty string in place of NaN

df = df.join(roles)
df = df.join(names)

df = df.drop(columns=['participants'])  # remove old column

pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100
print(df.to_string())
```

Result:

```
                 Participant #1 Role        Participant #2 Role Participant #3 Role     Participant #1 Name    Participant #2 Name Participant #3 Name
0  director,founder,owner,real_owner                                                              Lichun Du                                           
1                              board  director,board,real_owner    board,real_owner           Erik Mølgaard  Mikael Bodholdt Linde  Dorte Bøcker Linde
2                director,real_owner                      owner                      Kristian Løth Hougaard  WORLD JET HOLDING ApS
```

---

I used two function to get first only columns with roles and next columns only with names - but if you would need `role1, name1, role2, name2, role3, name3` then it could be done with one function.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'participants': 
[
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'founder'}, {'type': 'owner'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Lichun Du'}}],
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Erik Mølgaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Dorte Bøcker Linde'}}],
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Kristian Løth Hougaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'WORLD JET HOLDING ApS'}}],
]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_columns(cell):
    
    results = pd.Series(dtype=object)
    
    for number, item in enumerate(cell, 1):
        name = item['life']['name']
        results[f'Participant #{number} Name'] = name

        roles = [role['type'] for role in item['roles']]
        results[f'Participant #{number} Role'] = ",".join(roles)

    return results

columns = df['participants'].apply(get_columns)
names = columns.fillna('')  # put empty string in place of NaN

df = df.join(columns)
#print(df.columns)

df = df.drop(columns=['participants'])

pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100
print(df.to_string())
```

Result:

```
      Participant #1 Name                Participant #1 Role    Participant #2 Name        Participant #2 Role Participant #3 Name Participant #3 Role
0               Lichun Du  director,founder,owner,real_owner                    NaN                        NaN                 NaN                 NaN
1           Erik Mølgaard                              board  Mikael Bodholdt Linde  director,board,real_owner  Dorte Bøcker Linde    board,real_owner
2  Kristian Løth Hougaard                director,real_owner  WORLD JET HOLDING ApS                      owner                 NaN                 NaN
```

Comment: The problem is I need all the participant related columns as last columns in order because I have other columns in the data frame which I renamed and then rearranged via following code: responses = responses[["Name", "Ad Protection Status", "Street Name", "From Street No.", "Postal Code", "City", "Credit Status Code", "Bankrupcy Status"....and so on.]]
How to reorder them such that all these participant related columns are added as the last columns following the order: Participant#1 Name, Participant#1 Role, Participant#2 Name, Participant#2 Role.....Participant#N Name, Participant#N Role.

Comment: did you try it ? `join()` should add new columns at the end.

Comment: BTW: in question you show order `role1, role2, role3, name1, name2, name3` so I created this order but putting code from `get_names` `get_names` in one function with one Series and one `for`-loop you could get order. `role1, name1, role2, name2, role3, name3.`

Comment: you can always create new `df` using columns in order which you need `new_df = df[ ["role1", "name1", "role2", "name2", "role3", "name3"] ]`

Comment: I added code which add in order `name1, role1, name2, role2, name3, role3`

Comment: Join didn't add the new columns at the end. Also I cannot know how many participants related column will be generated to use solution like new_df= df[[name1, role1...] But maybe I can order the other column in a a separate df and concat them with the participant related columns.

Comment: You are the best and true savior!!

Comment: simply use `if/else` like in your other question  [python - Pandas- Error in creating dynamic columns from existing column having nested list of lists - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69992468/pandas-error-in-creating-dynamic-columns-from-existing-column-having-nested-lis) - but you will have to increate number using `number += 1` instead of `enumerate()`

Comment: Some times the role object is not available as property of each element of list, how to handle that?

Comment: as always use `if/else` for this.

Comment: in the get_column function, how I can exclude name and roles of participants after 10th participants? I want to show upto 10th participant for each row of company data or less if it have less than 10? Please give me some suggestions atleast

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something link this?

```py
# Extract the value from the "type" property of each subobject of each row
df['roles'] = df['roles'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(t['type'] for t in x))

# Extract the value of "name" from the subobject of each row
df['life'] = df['life'].str['name']

# Rename 'life' column to 'name' (optional)
df = df.rename({'life': 'name'}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
                         roles                   name
0                        board          Erik Mølgaard
1  director, board, real_owner  Mikael Bodholdt Linde
2            board, real_owner     Dorte Bøcker Linde
```

Try:

```py
>>> df[df['name'] == 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde']
                         roles                   name
1  director, board, real_owner  Mikael Bodholdt Linde


>>> df[df['name'] == 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde']['roles']
1    director, board, real_owner
Name: roles, dtype: object


>>> df[df['name'] == 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde']['roles'].iloc[0]
'director, board, real_owner'


>>> df[df['name'] == 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde']['roles'].iloc[0].split(', ')
['director', 'board', 'real_owner']
```

Comment: There are two rows of data if you see in the question and the output should be also two row just like the image. However your output has 3 rows which should be a single row like the image in the question. Thats why its a problem I am still struggling to solve.

Comment: I have reedited the questions for more clarity.