# Error in creating dynamic columns from existing column having nested list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, nested-lists

I want to create two column from an existing column which contains nested list of list as values.

**Rows of record consisting of 3 companies participant and their role:**

```
**row 1** [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'founder'}, {'type': 'owner'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Lichun Du'}}]

**row 2** [{'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Erik Mølgaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Dorte Bøcker Linde'}}]

**row 3** [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Kristian Løth Hougaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'WORLD JET HOLDING ApS'}}]
```

So far I have tried:

```
    responses['Role of Participant(s)'] = [element[0]['roles'] for element in responses['participants']]
    responses['Role of Participant(s)'] = responses['Role of Participant(s)'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(t['type'] for t in x))
    responses['Name of Participant(s)'] = [element[0]['life']['name'] for element in responses['participants']]
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image]

It just returns me only the first participants's role and name .

However, I need all the participant and their respective roles of each row/records like the following:

[image]

So how can I achieve this using "***" as separator for each rows value like the above screenshot?

### Update

Here is the csv version of the dataframe:

```
participants
"[{'roles': [{'type': 'founder'}], 'life': {'name': 'Poul Erik Andersen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Martin Ravn-Nielsen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Søren Haugaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Mads Dehlsen Winther'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'founder'}], 'life': {'name': 'M+ Ejendomme A/S'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'founder'}], 'life': {'name': 'MILTON HOLDING HORSENS A/S'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'accountant'}], 'life': {'name': 'EY Godkendt Revisionspartnerselskab'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'HUSCOMPAGNIET HOLDING A/S'}}]"
"[{'roles': [{'type': 'founder'}, {'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Rasmus Gert Hansen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'John Nyrup Larsen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Ole Nidolf Larsen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'RASMUS HANSEN HOLDING ApS'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'accountant'}], 'life': {'name': 'DANSK REVISION SLAGELSE GODKENDT REVISIONSAKTIESELSKAB'}}]"
"[{'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Berit Pedersen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Sanne Kristine Späth'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Kjeld Kirk Kristiansen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'director'}], 'life': {'name': 'Jesper Andersen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Poul Hartvig Nielsen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Nanna Birgitta Gudum'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Henrik Baagøe Fredeløkke'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Carsten Rasmussen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Jesper Laursen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'John Hansen'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'LEGO A/S'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'accountant'}], 'life': {'name': 'PRICEWATERHOUSECOOPERS STATSAUTORISERET REVISIONSPARTNERSELSKAB'}}]"
```

Comment: it will need second `for`-loop instead of `[0]`.

Comment: better put data as `DataFrame()` so we could simply copy it and use in solutions.

Comment: Hi, @furas, I have updated my question with participant.csv which can be downloaded and converted into dataframe (as I dont know how to convert it and share it as dataframe here)

Comment: frankly, people rather don't like to download external files and convert to dataframe. And if you delete file then link will be useless. You should rather put example data directly in question.

Comment: @furas, make sense, I have put the example csv data directly in the question.

Comment: now you can copy example data from my answer ;) it is already as `DataFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need second `for`-loop instead of `[0]`

I use normal function instead of `lambda` to make it more readable.

First for **role**:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'participants': 
[
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'founder'}, {'type': 'owner'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Lichun Du'}}],
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Erik Mølgaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Dorte Bøcker Linde'}}],
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Kristian Løth Hougaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'WORLD JET HOLDING ApS'}}],
]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_roles(cell):
    
    results = []
    
    for item in cell:
        roles = []
        for role in item['roles']:
            roles.append(role['type'])
        results.append(",".join(roles))
    
    results = "***".join(results)

    return results

df['Role of Participant(s)'] = df['participants'].apply(get_roles)

print(df[['Role of Participant(s)']].to_string())
```

Result:

```
                                 Role of Participant(s)
0                     director,founder,owner,real_owner
1  board***director,board,real_owner***board,real_owner
2                           director,real_owner***owner
```

And now you can try to write as `lambda`

```
df['Role of Participant(s)'] = df['participants'].apply(lambda cell:"***".join([",".join(role['type'] for role in item['roles']) for item in cell]))
```

---

Similar for **name**:

```
def get_names(cell):
    
    results = []
    
    for item in cell:
        results.append(item['life']['name'])
    
    results = "***".join(results)

    return results

df['Name of Participant(s)'] = df['participants'].apply(get_names)
```

And now with `lambda`

```
df['Name of Participant(s)'] = df['participants'].apply(lambda cell:"***".join(item['life']['name'] for item in cell))
```

---

**EDIT:**

version which create both column in one `apply` and skip participants which have role `director`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'participants': 
[
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'founder'}, {'type': 'owner'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Lichun Du'}}],
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'board'}], 'life': {'name': 'Erik Mølgaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Mikael Bodholdt Linde'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'board'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Dorte Bøcker Linde'}}],
    [{'roles': [{'type': 'director'}, {'type': 'real_owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'Kristian Løth Hougaard'}}, {'roles': [{'type': 'owner'}], 'life': {'name': 'WORLD JET HOLDING ApS'}}],
]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_names_and_roles(cell):
    
    all_names = []
    all_roles = []
    
    for item in cell:
        name = item['life']['name']
        roles = [role['type'] for role in item['roles']]

        if 'director' not in roles:
            all_names.append(name)
            all_roles.append(",".join(roles))
    
    all_names = "***".join(all_names)
    all_roles = "***".join(all_roles)

    return pd.Series([all_names, all_roles])


df[ ['Name of Participant(s)', 'Role of Participant(s)'] ] = df['participants'].apply(get_names_and_roles)

print(df[ ['Name of Participant(s)', 'Role of Participant(s)'] ].to_string())
```

Result:

```
               Name of Participant(s)    Role of Participant(s)
0                                                              
1  Erik Mølgaard***Dorte Bøcker Linde  board***board,real_owner
2               WORLD JET HOLDING ApS                     owner
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I am getting participants role of all the rows in a single row which makes it tough to understand  which participant belongs to which row. I want to use "***" as seperator for participants role of each rows. I was using the lambda solution

Comment: it will need to add `**` between `for`-loops - so it would be very difficult to convert to `lambda`

Comment: Okay so how can it be done without lamdas?

Comment: I put new version in answer - now it add `***` between users in both columns. BTW: in Stockoverflow you can use `Markdown` which uses `**` to create **bold text** and I thought you used `***` also to "bold" differences between results.

Comment: You are GREAT and a LIFE SAVER!! If you dont mind me asking, what if I want to omit participants name along with their role where their role is director, board or both? 

Also I actually needed to make dynamic column based on number of participants. I have another stackoverflow question if you consider to give a thought. Fingers crossed

Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943932/pandas-create-dynamic-columns-from-a-single-columns-values

Comment: to omit both values you would have to generate two columns directly in one `apply()` and result assign to `df[ ['Role of Participant(s)', 'Name of Participant(s)'] ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239293/discussion-between-shihab-ullah-and-furas).

Comment: `columns based on number of participants` doesn't sound as good idea. It is simpler to search name in one culumn with list or dictionary then in many columns. OR convert every `Participant` in separated row. Pandas has `explode` for this.

Comment: I added example which create two columns in one `apply` and it skip participants with role `directory`

Comment: To convert every participant in seperate row will be helpful. How can I achieve participant roles and its user to explode for each given row of records?

Comment: first run `df = df.explode('participants')` and you will have every `participant` in separated row - but still as dictionaries so it will still need `apply()` to put names in one column and roles in other column.